# Why is a sublist mutable in a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, sublist, mutability

I am a beginner in python and I find this about mutabilty quite confusing and non intuitive. Given a list:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And trying to change the list within a for-loop.

```
for i in lst:
    i = "test"
```

I understand that this does not change the list. But:

```
for i in lst:
    i[1] = "test"
```

I was surprised that referring to the sublist led to following outcome:

```
[[1, 'test', 3], [4, 'test', 6]]
```

I tried to understand with a visualizer but I don't get it. Would anybody please explain this in plain words? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment (which is what the `=` operator does) assigns a value to a name.

`i` is a variable name in the local namespace.  At the time it runs inside the for loop, it refers to a list.  By assigning a string to it, you cause the name to no longer refer to a list, but instead refer to the string.  The list is unaffected -- the only thing that changes is the value associated with the name.

`i[1]` is a name that specifies a specific location inside one of the two lists, depending on what `i` is set to at the time.  By assigning a string to it, you cause the name to no longer refer to the object that previously occupied that space inside the list (an integer, `2` or `5` depending on the list) and instead refer to the string.  The integer is unaffected -- the only thing that changes is the value associated with the name.

So in each case, assignment is doing the same thing -- it's making a name refer to a new thing instead of the old thing it referred to.  The difference is that the second case is a special name in that it refers to a property of a mutable object.

Comment: Thank you, running the code in the visualizer again and following your explanation helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, you simply have a copied reference to the element.

```
i ---> lst[n]
```

In the latter case, you are *dereferencing* the reference, and changing data (not in a copy):

```
i[i] ---> lst[n][i]
```

Therefore assigning  to `i[n]` will point to the actual mutable object, not a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

`for` does not make copies of each element it yields. As such, the yielded object retains all the properties of the original (since it *is* the original), including mutability.

Answer (score 0):

since for loop in case of string is called in different way
like 
for i in lst:

it means if lst is list or array of string then i is referenced to the value of x[i] directly that is why in first case result was "test " two times because length of "lst" was just 2

while in second case i[1] means 
i ------lst[i]
i[1]--------`-lst[i][1]  means
first value equal lst[0][1]---[1,'test',3]
second value equal lst[1][1]--[4,'test',6]